# Using .getElementsByTagName on HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I have to select multiple input tags by NAME from multiple forms.

I selected the forms using getElementsByTagName('forms') (which returns a HTML Collection as far as I understand). When I try to apply the getElementsByName('example') i get the undefined TypeError. After doing some reading I've found out that HTML Collection does not have that method. My question is what method should I use to select the input fields by name in this case?

(Note: I can't use jQuery on this project.)

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.
Cheers!

Edit: Here's a code i'm working on. One of the constraints in this project is that I don't know how many forms there will be on the website, or how many input boxes those forms will have. (FieldObj is an object that contains the names of input fields)

```
var formsList = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

var form;
for (form in formsList) {
    var currentForm = formsList[form];
    for (field in fieldObj) {
        if (formsList.getElementsByName(field)) {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Nick Bailey Added, please see the edit

Comment: Presumably, fieldObj is defined somewhere else? Or is it undefined? Also, check to make sure that fieldObj correctly has values that you expect and that your forms are named as you expect.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg yes fieldObject is defined outside the function (the function itself is in a namespace that accepts the fieldObject variable as a parameter, i left that part out of the snippet). Double checked the fieldObject variable, everything seems to be in order, thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, still struggling with this problem though...

Comment: Then, please post an html snippet as well as the contents of the fieldObj object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fieldObj variable in your code is undefined. I would loop forms in this way:

```
var formsList = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for (var i=0; i < formsList.length; i++) {
    var form = formsList[i];
    for (field in form) {
        var value = form[field].value;
    }
}
```